# Notation of an ideal generated by an ideal and an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

**Question is actually this one:** 
Let $R\neq\{ 0 \}$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $I$ is an ideal of
$R$ and $a\in R$
 Show that $(I, a) = \{u + ra | u ∈ I, r ∈ R\}$. (Here $(I, a)$
is the ideal generated by I and a).
**So, what is the definition of $(I,a)$$?$ I know that $(a,b)=\{ax+by| x,y \in R\}$**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $(I,a)$ is the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $a$
and so also the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $(a)$. Such an ideal
must contain $I+(a)$ (why?) and as $I+(a)$ is an ideal, then $(I,a)=I+(a)$.